# Is the part in the bracket ( a or b ) OR (a, or b, c, d, and e)?

Tags: grammar

"Such uses express (physical superiority, or superiority of position, skill, technical ability, and command of tools,) mechanical or fiscal." (Source: Democracy and Education by John Dewey)
Is the part in the parenthesis (A or B)   OR
(A or B, C, D and E) structure?  Which one is correct, the former or the latter?   Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you.

Comment: This is ambiguous. It can mean (a OR b) AND (c, d, e and f); or it can mean (a) OR (b, c, d, e and f); or it can mean (a OR b, c and d) AND f; and there's probably another way to read it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Davo that the list is ambiguous. Looking at the context, the list appears to be this:

1. superiority, either physical or of position
2. skill
3. technical ability
4. command of tools, either mechanical or fiscal

Assuming I am correct, I would reword it this way:

> Such uses express physical superiority or superiority of position, skill, technical ability, and command of mechanical or fiscal tools.

It's still a bit of a mouthful, but it's easier to parse when the members of the list are the only items separated by commas.